# Matching a multiple lines pattern via PHP's preg_match()

Tags: regex, preg-match

How can I match *subject* via a PHP preg_match() regular expression pattern in this HTML code:

```
      <table border=0>
  <tr>
  <td>


  <h2>subject</h2>



    </td>
```

All the whitespaces and newlines are left on purpose. So the problem is in extracting subject name using some multiple line pattern.

Comment: This article may useful [multiline-searches-with-preg_match-in](https://blog-en.openalfa.com/multiline-searches-with-preg_match-in-php)

Answer (score 68):

If you're looking for (e.g.) a `h2` tag nested *within* a `td` tag where there's only whitespace in between the two, just use `\s` which includes spaces, newlines, etc. eg::

```
preg_match('#<td>\s*<h2>(.*?)</h2>\s*</td>#i',$str,$matches);
// result is in $matches[1]
```

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?2vppb).

For your interest, [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is a list of different modifiers you can pass in to `preg_*` functions. Flags that may interest you are:

- `s` ("dotall") : this one makes `.` match every character, *including* newlines. So, say your `<h2>.....</h2>` was spread over multiple lines. Then you'd have to do

  ```
  preg_match('#<td>\s*<h2>(.*?)</h2>\s*</td>#is',$str,$matches);
  ```

  in order to have the `.*` go over multiple lines (see the extra `s` at the end of the regex?).
- `m` ("multiline") : this one just lets `^` and `$` match start/end of *line* instead of just the start/end of *string*. You only really need it if you're using `^` and `$` in your pattern and want them to match the start/end of each individual line in your input.

Comment: Man... I was stuck for 1.5 hour until I found your post. Thanks! The "s" attribute is what I was looking for.

Comment: I was wanting to match the start of a particular line in multi-line input, so `'/^start/im'`

Answer (score 15):

You can add the `m` operator to your regular expression:

```
// Given your HTML content.
$html = 'Your HTML content';
preg_match('/<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/im', $html, $matches);
```

Hope this (still) helps, hahaha.

Comment: I think the `s` modifier (for "DOTALL" or "single-line" mode) is what you're thinking of, and that's already been [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8959000/20938).

Comment: This hahaha is very disturbing.

Comment: try also adding "sU" in addition to "m" if needed

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML content. It can cause a lot of issues if you cannot control what the user can input. There are a lot of better solutions in every language. An XML parser in most of the cases is doing a better job. Check out [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [php-html-parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser)

See here for more answers why you shouldn't use regex on HTML content:
*[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)*

Comment: I was looking for this answer. I was surprised that 5 years later nobody suggested that maybe it's a bad idea to parse html with regex. Don't understand why it's downvoted.

Comment: Yep, welcome to the club. I still stand by my answer, though :)

Comment: This is definitely the way to approach this. Gave it another upvote at least :-)

Comment: I haven’t voted on this, but I might add that it misses the point of the question, which is how to use `preg_match` with multiple lines. It is _not_ answering the question if you don’t like the use case.

Comment: Hmm. I think I am offering better solutions than one provided. If someone uses the wrong tool shouldn't I tell them they do and offer better alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Very simply with

```
preg_match('/<h2>(.*?)<\\/h2>/', $str, $matches);
print($matches[1]);
```

The multi-line format has no effect on the regex unless you need to match a string that spans multiple lines.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. The problem is in the lack of "identifiers" in the HTML code i am dealing with. There can be some other h2 tags and others. So i am trying to use the surrounding tags to exactly target this particular place in the code. So how can i make regex patterns understand multilines?...

Answer (score 0):

Catch a block of code separated by 4 four backticks (as the markdown syntax).

Example to be adapted easily.

`````
<?php

$str = '
# Some Text

```` 
    h5 {
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
````

And some text.
';

$reg = '/````[^>]*(.*?)````/';

preg_match($reg, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];

/* OUTPUT
```` 
    h5 {
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
````
*/

echo preg_replace($reg, "DELETED", $str);

/* OUTPUT
# Some Text

DELETED

And some text.
*/
`````

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: Matching a multiple lines pattern via PHP's preg_match()

Comment: Found this answer in the search for the 'inverted pattern'. So if I find a match across multiple lines how do I *not* return any matches at all, any ideas?

Answer (score -5):

You have to remove all line breaks using `\s` in the regular expression:

```
$str ="<ol>
         <li>Capable for unlimited product</li>
         <li>Two currency support</li>
         <li>Works with touch screens and click screen based systems</li>
         <li>Responsive design <b>shopping cart</b>, Specially design for Mac, iPhone, iPad, PC and Android</li>
         <li>VAT for countries that support a Value Added Tax</li>
         <li>Barcode scanner checkout option for POS</li>
         <li>mRSS</li>
       </ol>";

preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9\s\<\>\.\,\/\-\ ]+)$/", $str);

// Sanitize your code before save to database.

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = json_encode($data);
    $data = addslashes($data);
    return $data;
}

echo test_input($str);
```

Comment: I think he want's to preserve new lines