# Finding comments in a string

Tags: php, regex, file, comments

I have file which has comments at the top.

e.g.

```
/**
 * Comments for file.
 *
 */
```

Using PHP, I read content of file using file_get_contents into variable now I want to get value present inside comment. For above example expected result would be

```
* Comments for file
*
*
```

Which means I want content inside those /** and */. This file can have multiple comments but I want the very first which is at the top of file.

Any ideas/help please ?

**UPDATE**:- It is normal text file. Not PHP file.

Comment: Is the 'file' a PHP file? A PHP class?

Comment: Using a parser like https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/releases/tag/v0.9.4 might help; annotation libraries like https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php might also be useful depending on what you want to do with the comments

Comment: In what language is written the file?

Comment: What about the other comment delimiters of // and # ?

Comment: The reflection API has a [method for getting DocBlock comments](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) from PHP code. It may be helpful if you are trying to get the comments from a PHP file.

Comment: @jeff, as stated in the question, they're strictly concerned with the first `/*` comment.

Comment: Yes strictly with the first comments and its not PHP file but normal text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Dipesh Parmar good answer, an example:

```
$subject =<<<'LOD'
sdf df sdf sdf 
sdf sdf sdf sdf
<?php 
/**
* Youhou!!
*
* HiHa!
*
*/
LOD;

$tokens = token_get_all($subject);

foreach($tokens as $token) {
    if (is_array($token)&&$token[0]==T_DOC_COMMENT) {
        echo substr(substr($token[1],4),0,-3);
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice: this work if and only if the subject contains `<?php`, otherwhise comments are seen as simple text by the tokenizer. If `<?php` is missing you can easily add it before the subject:

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php'.$subject);
```

You can do it systematically, it's not a problem to have two `<?php` for this task.

Comment: Sorry Casimir and thanks for the information but its not php file but txt file.

Comment: @UmakantPatil: Then it works if you use the trick in the notice part.

Answer (score 6):

You can read comment using [**tokenizer**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php)

```
$source = file_get_contents('example.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
```

Comment: I would have mentioned earlier its no PHP file. It is txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/\*{2}\s(.*?)\s\*/`

Regards.

Comment: This does not get me result.  May be because of new line characters. I'm using preg_match for this.

Comment: I'm not in to PHP at all, but from what I found in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958310/matching-multiple-lines-pattern-via-php-preg-match](this) discussion something like `preg_match('#\*{2}\s(.*?)\s\*/#s',$str,$matches);` might do the trick. The trick being the s after the ending delimiter meaning PCRE_DOTALL, i.e. '.' will match new-line characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a `PHP` class, then you can use the `ReflectionClass::getDocComment` and `ReflectionMethod::getDocComment`

e.g

```
$instance = new ClassWithComments();
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($instance);
echo $reflectionCLass->getDocComment();
```

Comment: Sorry its not PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

the standard recommendation is to use a parser instead of regex.

however `^/\*(([^*]*[*]*[^*/])+)\*/` should do the trick in your case. remember to enable multiline-matching in your regex engine. capture group 1 contains the result.

Comment: Thanks, How would I enable multi-line matching in PHP?

Comment: And even if I use this with preg_match it would result me with error  :- Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '*' in test.php on line 12