# regex wrap li with ul

Tags: php, regex

I need to wrap multiple groups of li tags with ul tags. Here is a sample:

```
<text>
<p>Today is a nice day</p>
<li>This is line one</li>
<li>This is line two</li>
<li>This is line three</li>
</text>
<text>
<p>Today is also a nice day</p>
<li>This is also line one</li>
<li>This is also line two</li>
<li>This is also line three</li>
</text>
```

Here is the regex that I am using:

```html
/(<li>.*?<\/li>)+/g
```

When I try to replace the selected string with:

```html
<ul>$1</ul>
```

I get the following:

```
<text>
<p>Today is a nice day</p>
<ul><li>This is line one</li></ul>
<ul><li>This is line two</li></ul>
<ul><li>This is line three</li></ul>
</text>
<text>
<p>Today is also a nice day</p>
<ul><li>This is also line one</li></ul>
<ul><li>This is also line two</li></ul>
<ul><li>This is also line three</li></ul>
</text>
```

Here is what I want the result to look like:

```
<text>
<p>Today is a nice day</p>
<ul><li>This is line one</li></ul>
<ul><li>This is line two</li></ul>
<ul><li>This is line three</li></ul>
</text>
<text>
<p>Today is also a nice day</p>
<ul>
<li>This is also line one</li>
<li>This is also line two</li>
<li>This is also line three</li>
</ul>
</text>
```

Comment: Why you want to get the result like above?

Comment: use [domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of regex

Answer (score 1):

You have to match all the `<il>` tags in one single match, so you need to use some flavor of multiline mode: `s` modifier makes `.` match against newline:

```
/(</p><li>.*?</li></text>)+/is
```

Also check [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958310/matching-multiple-lines-pattern-via-php-preg-match)