# RegEX to match all between tags with PHP

Tags: php, regex

So I'm writing a script which will take everything between two div tags, the way I have it seemed to be working but it's not matching everything I noticed, I'm not sure why, whether it's because of line breaks, or any other issue. I want literally everything (including other html tags) matched.

```
     $aPost = preg_match_all('#<div class="posttext">(.*?)</div>#', $rThread, $aPosts);
```

It appears as if it's only matching whatever is written on one line with no line breaks, and if the div doesn't meet that criteria is ignores it entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Try the `m` switch for multiline support: `#<div class="posttext">(.*?)</div>#im` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754347/3711660

Comment: Use `(?s)<div class="posttext">(.*?)</div>`

Answer (score 1):

To fix your regex, use the *dotall* modifier which forces the `.` to match newline sequences:

```
preg_match_all('~<div class="posttext">(.*?)</div>~si', $rThread, $aPosts);
```

But, I would avoid using regex and make effective use of [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and **XPath** to do this for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="posttext"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```